# Sticky grid header not working on some Android version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle

I am using Sticky grid header with below app Gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.tonicartos:stickygridheaders:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

And build tool version are

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stickyheader"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName '3'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

 }
```

Curruntly Using android studio 2.2.3.
before I update Android studio it works fine for all device, also below kitkat version.
In some Devices Specifically below kitkat it crash and above kitkat version Code is workling fine.

In Below version of kitkat device I got This Error,
**Stack trace**

> 04-14 10:32:13.520 24869-24869/com.example.stickyheader
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.stickyheader/com.example.stickyheader.CustomerEventDetailActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62:
>   Error inflating class
>   com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)

In Addition This is my Xml Code for Sticky grid header.

```
 <com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/gridViewCustomer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:columnWidth="250dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"/>
```

It seems like It will Give Error because of appCompact version which is defind in dependances in build.gradle (I am not sure) .

enable to handle this error.

I also try to comment this dependancy

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

but not working.

Thank You :)

Comment: The librarywhich you are using is very old , I would recommend using some libray which is active

Comment: can you suggest me any example/library which are latest?

Comment: Check https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerStickyHeaderView
and
https://github.com/Codewaves/Sticky-Header-Grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a library issue. Also the stacktrace you have posted does not have any info about the crash reason.
 The library you are using is very old and abandoned . Read [ReadME.MD](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/README.md).

So there is no support from the developer of this library its useless to open a issue . you should try some other solution . You can try [This one](https://github.com/Codewaves/Sticky-Header-Grid) or similar with `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutmanager`.

Comment: Yes.. actually I have to switch library which.. because this is too old for latest versions., And I am stuck for too many days.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using [this](https://github.com/Codewaves/Sticky-Header-Grid), its not that old and should work fine with appcompat

firstly add this dependency

```
compile 'com.codewaves.stickyheadergrid:stickyheadergrid:0.9.6'
```

1. Implement an adapter by subclassing `StickyHeaderGridAdapter`
2. Create holder class for each header and item type. Use `HeaderViewHolder` and `ItemViewHolder` as base classes.
3. Override and implement `getSectionCount()`, `getSectionItemCount(int section)`, `onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerType)`, `onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemType)`, `onBindHeaderViewHolder(HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int section)`, `onBindItemViewHolder(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int section, int offset)`.
4. Create a `StickyHeaderGridLayoutManager` with required column count and assign it to your `RecyclerView`.
5. Use only `StickyHeaderGridAdapter::notify*` methods

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using this library: https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders.

**Add it to you dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
   compile "com.tonicartos:stickygridheaders:1.0.1"
}
```